# Setting Test Suite to Ignore

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite

I have many Test Suites with each one contains many Test Classes. Here is how they look like:

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( {ATest.class, BTest.class})
public class MyFirstTestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
                // load resources
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
        // release resources

    }
}
```

Sometimes I want to disable a whole Test Suite completely. I don't want to set each test class as `@Ignore`, since every test suite loads and releases resources using `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` and I want to skip this loading/releasing when the test suite is ignored.

So the question is: is there anything similar to `@Ignore` that I can use on a whole Test Suite?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can annotate the TestSuite with `@Ignore`.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({Test1.class})
@Ignore
public class MySuite {
    public MySuite() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("beforeClass");
    }
}
```

doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

SlowTest is a class defined by user. It can be empty (without any functions or attributes). You can name it whatever you want:

[image]

[image]